# Clock_gettime showing high usage during profiling of code

Tags: clock, libevent, gprof, gettimeofday

I am profiling a userland application on netbsd with gprof and seeing clock_gettime using upwards of 30% cycles. Gprof does not show where it is getting called from (it shows some function which clearly does not call clock_getttime).
The application uses third party code including libevent 1.4 (which appears to use clock_gettime). I looked into removing the call from that but could not determine much.

1. I don't understand why it would take that much of time. Any inputs will be appreciated. I also saw gettimeofday taking a lot of cycles. In general, why would getting the time involve so many processing cycles
2. Is there a way that one can optimize clock_gettime () or can we use any other call?
3. Is it possible that gcc itself adds this call to the code when it is compiled with -pg for profiling purposes?
   Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all relative to whatever else your program is doing, and keep in mind that if you're doing any I/O, the actual CPU time your program uses may be small, and `gprof` doesn't see anything else.
So if some calls to timing routines get stuck in there, and they are called often enough, sure they can show a high percent.

Why doesn't `gprof` show where they're being called from?
For routines compiled with -pg, it tries to figure out who the caller is when any routine is entered.
It tries, but that doesn't mean it succeeds.
Anyway, [*that's `gprof`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771).

Comment: Thanks. Are there any way to optimize clock_gettime or compare performance of different timers that clock_gettime can potentially use

Comment: @doon: See, I don't optimize that way. I look for what in my own code is responsible for time being spent. [*I use this method.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771)